# How to create a graph like this in matplotlib about novel corona virus?

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization, data-science

I am relatively new to data science and trying to investigate about corona virus. I want to create a graph like this:

[image]

Dates in the x axis. And cases/deaths in y axis.

My dataset is like this:

[image]

I especially want to investigate the spread speed of the virus by researching the distribution. Would be glad if you could help me.

Comment: Kindly provide a minimun reproducible example, so that other people may help you and try with you data easier and faster, with minimum data but enough to work with it.

Comment: If you are talking about the dataset, I got it from kaggle. You can check it out by clicking [here](https://www.kaggle.com/sudalairajkumar/novel-corona-virus-2019-dataset) @alan.elkin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following might help:

**1. Plot confirmed cases (top 15):**

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

confirmed = pd.read_csv('time_series_covid_19_confirmed.csv')
confirmed = confirmed.drop(['Province/State', 'Lat', 'Long'], axis = 1).set_index(['Country/Region'])

confirmed.groupby(confirmed.index).sum().sort_values(by=confirmed.iloc[:,-1].name, ascending=False).head(15).T.plot(figsize=(16, 10), rot=90, title='Confirmed cases (Top 15)', legend=True)
plt.show()
```

[image]

**2. Plot recovered cases (top 15):**

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

recovered = pd.read_csv('time_series_covid_19_recovered.csv')
recovered = recovered.drop(['Province/State', 'Lat', 'Long'], axis = 1).set_index(['Country/Region'])

recovered.groupby(recovered.index).sum().sort_values(by=recovered.iloc[:,-1].name, ascending=False).head(15).T.plot(figsize=(16, 10), rot=90, title='Recovered (Top 15)', legend=True)
plt.show()
```

[image]

**3. Plot deaths (top 15):**

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

deaths = pd.read_csv('time_series_covid_19_deaths.csv')
deaths = deaths.drop(['Province/State', 'Lat', 'Long'], axis = 1).set_index(['Country/Region'])

deaths.groupby(deaths.index).sum().sort_values(by=deaths.iloc[:,-1].name, ascending=False).head(15).T.plot(figsize=(16, 10), rot=90, title='Deaths (Top 15)', legend=True)
plt.show()
```

[image]

---

**Edit:**

Graphs above are on a **linear** scale. Adding **`plt.yscale('log')`** before **`plt.show()`** will show graphs in **logarithmic** scale.

Comment: You might want to throw a `ax.set_yscale("log")` somewhere because it's hard to read in linear scale.

Comment: @Guimoute I think adding `plt.yscale('log')` before `plt.show()` will convert graphs in log scale.